# C++ 'bracket' operators

Tags: c++, class, if-statement, operators

In c++ when you use if you use these kinds of curly brackets:

```
if (x == y)
{ <---
} <---
```

Is it possible to create a class which uses these? Somewhere similar to this:

```
class x
{
    operator {} foo(int something)
    {
        do something...
    }
};
```

PS. I have no idea what these brackets are called, curly brackets?

Thank You

Comment: I think the preferred nomenclature is either curly brackets or curly braces.

Comment: Well you've been told it's imposible, but the obvious question is what you were hoping to achieve with this? What problem are you trying to solve? There might be another way.

Comment: Sometimes they're called "braces" (dropping the 'curly'). It's probably only wise to do so if you *consistently* refer to `()` as "parentheses", `[]` as "brackets" and `{}` as "braces".

Comment: There is no problem, this is just pure curiosity.

Comment: You can always use lambdas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Curly braces are actually used for many different things:

- Compound statements
- Initializers
- Struct/enum/class/union/namespace specifier

(there's probably a few more too!)

None of these are operators and none of these can be overloaded.

What you may be interested in is C++11's brace initialization syntax which can you could use if you want a certain syntax:

```
class x
{
    x(int something)
    {
        do something...
    }
};

x foo{5};
```

Comment: Well, it's not the answer, but it's close enough!

Answer (score 4):

No, because the curly brackets aren't an operator, and you can't create new operators - you may only overload the existing ones.

Answer (score 2):

Yup, they're called curly brackets or curly braces or curlies. They denote a block or a group of initializer values. You can't redefine their meaning.

Answer (score 1):

(They are called curly brackets or curly braces, as far as I'm concerned.)

**And they're not operators.**

In the example with the `if ()` you provided, they define the bounds of a scope. Or when it comes to OO, they define a namespace. Or a class.

And I believe you can't overload them (that would make no sense, really.)